# Array of Hashes push into another Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, loops

I've an array contains hashes, I want to filter few parameters from the hash and insert the filtered data in another array but am not succeed below is the sample data I've used

```
a = Array.new
a = [
  {"name"=>"hello", "age"=>"12", "sex"=> "M", "city"=>"Chennai"},
  {"name"=>"name2", "age"=>"26", "sex"=> "M", "city"=>"Banglore"}
]
line_item = Array.new
hash_data = {}

a.each do |datas|
  hash_data[:name] = datas["name"]
  hash_data[:age] = datas["age"]
  line_item << hash_data
end
```

I am getting this result:

```
[
  {:name=>"name2", :age=>"26"},
  {:name=>"name2", :age=>"26"}
]
```

But am expecting this:

```
[
  {:name=>"hello", :age=>"12"},
  {:name=>"name2", :age=>"26"}
]
```

Somebody please help to sort out this, Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have to create an empty array via `a = Array.new`, simply use `a = [...]`.

Answer (score 7):

Defining the hash outside the loop means that you keep adding the same hash object again (while overwriting its previous values). Instead, create a fresh hash *within* the loop:

```
line_items = []
a.each do |datas|
  hash_data = {}
  hash_data[:name] = datas["name"]
  hash_data[:age] = datas["age"]
  line_items << hash_data
end
```

The code looks a bit unidiomatic. Let's refactor it.

We can set the keys right within the hash literal:

```
line_items = []
a.each do |datas|
  hash_data = { name: datas["name"], age: datas["age"] }
  line_items << hash_data
end
```

We can get rid of the `hash_data` variable:

```
line_items = []
a.each do |datas|
  line_items << { name: datas["name"], age: datas["age"] }
end
```

And we can use `map` to directly transform the array:

```
line_items = a.map { |h| { name: h["name"], age: h["age"] } }
#=> [{:name=>"hello", :age=>"12"}, {:name=>"name2", :age=>"26"}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the expected result with a combination of [`map`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/map) and [`slice`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice)

```
a = [
  {"name"=>"hello", "age"=>"12", "sex"=> "M", "city"=>"Chennai"},
  {"name"=>"name2", "age"=>"26", "sex"=> "M", "city"=>"Banglore"}
]

a.map{ |e| e.slice("name", "age") }
#=> [{"name"=>"hello", "age"=>"12"}, {"name"=>"name2", "age"=>"26"}]
```

- `map`: Returns `Array` containing the values returned by block
- `slice`: Returns `Hash` including only the specified keys

Comment: Argh there's the method -- `slice` -- whose name eluded me. This should be the accepted answer imo.

Comment: `Hash.slice` is evidently a Rails method. A similar pure-Ruby solutions would be `a.map { |e| e.select { |k,_| ["name", "age"].include?(k) }`, which uses [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-select).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ruby 2.5 incorporated [`Hash#slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-slice)

Comment: @Stefan, thanks, good to know. I've got to get with the program. I'm still using v2.4.

Answer (score 2):

In your loop you are essentially populating `line_item` with `hash_data` twice. This is the same object however. You can remedy this by using `.dup`.

```
a.each do |datas|
  hash_data[:name]=datas["name"]
  hash_data[:age]=datas["age"]
  line_item << hash_data.dup # <- here
end

irb(main):044:0> line_item
=> [{:name=>"hello", :age=>"12"}, {:name=>"name2", :age=>"26"}]
```

Edit: I prefer rado's suggestion of moving your definition of `hash_data` inside the loop over using `.dup`. It solves the problem more than treating the symptom.

Answer (score 2):

I think a lot of people are over complicating this.

You can achieve this using the following:

```
a.map { |hash| hash.select { |key, _value| key == 'name' || key == 'age' } }
```

If you want to return an array, you should nearly always be using [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map), and [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) simply selects the key - value pairs that match the criteria.

If you're set on having symbols as the keys, you can call [`symbolize_keys`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/symbolize_keys) on the result.

I'll expand the code so it's a little more readable, but the one liner above works perfectly:

```
a.map do |hash| 
  hash.select do |key, _value| 
    key == 'name' || key == 'age'
  end
end
```

Comment: Note: symbolize_keys is not core Ruby. It is a Rails method. Also, it doesn't work with nested hash

Comment: Thanks @AjayBarot - this is tagged Rails, so I thought it OK to add, though useful to have the note. This hash isn't nested so I went with that, otherwise there's [`deep_symbolize_keys`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/Hash/deep_symbolize_keys).

Answer (score 1):

On the first line `hash_data[:name]=datas["name"]` you are setting the key of the hash. That's why when the loop iterate again, it is overriding the value and after that push the new result to the hash.

One solution with reusing this code is just to put the `hash_data = {}` on the first line of your loop. This way you will have a brand new hash to work with on every iteration.

Also I would recommend you to read the docs about the Hash module. You will find more useful methods there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want for all keys you can do this

```
array     = [{"name"=>"hello", "age"=>"12", "sex"=> "M", "city"=>"Chennai"}, {"name"=>"name2", "age"=>"26""sex"=> "M", "city"=>"Banglore"}]

new_array = array.map{|b| b.inject({}){|array_obj,(k,v)| array_obj[k.to_sym] = v; array_obj}}
```

Ref: [inject](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject)

Happy Coding

Comment: If you want to build a new hash `each_with_object` would seem preferable to `inject` because it doesn't require that pesky `; array_obj`. However, the use of `Hash#select` or (the Rails method) `Hash.slice` is simpler.